# Display multiple markers, variable and array problems

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to display multiple markers on my map. I put the multiples location in adata-attribute trough my php file. Then I try to grab this information in my javascript one.

If I directly paste the coordinates, the markers appear. If I reference the data-attribute they don't. (The only difference is on the **line beginning with var locations**.)

This code works:

```
function GoogleMapsInit(){
setTimeout(function initialize() {
    var emplacements = $('#iframecarte').attr("data-emplacements");
    // Emplacements returns [[45.5314817,-73.1835154], [45.570004,-73.448701] ]
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.5580421, -73.7303025)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var locations = [[45.5314817,-73.1835154], [45.570004,-73.448701] ];

    var marker, i;
    var markers = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
      });

      markers.push(marker);

    }

}, 500);
}
```

This one doesn't:

```
function GoogleMapsInit(){
setTimeout(function initialize() {
    var emplacements = $('#iframecarte').attr("data-emplacements");
    // Emplacements returns [[45.5314817,-73.1835154], [45.570004,-73.448701] ]
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.5580421, -73.7303025)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var locations = emplacements;

    var marker, i;
    var markers = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
      });

      markers.push(marker);

    }

}, 500);
}
```

What is wrong with the variable locations when it references the emplacements variable so that the markers don't show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-working version emplacements is a string, not an array.

Convert the string to a javascript array:

```
var locations = JSON.parse(emplacements);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6q24u76u/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function GoogleMapsInit() {
  setTimeout(function initialize() {
    var emplacements = $('#iframecarte').attr("data-emplacements");
    // Emplacements returns [[45.5314817,-73.1835154], [45.570004,-73.448701] ]
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 9,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.5580421, -73.7303025)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var locations = JSON.parse(emplacements);

    var marker, i;
    var markers = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
      });

      markers.push(marker);

    }

  }, 500);
}
GoogleMapsInit();
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="iframecarte" data-emplacements="[[45.5314817,-73.1835154], [45.570004,-73.448701], [45.6066487,-73.712409]]"></div>
```

Comment: How should I convert it?